# How to use Struts 2 tags with bootstrap

Tags: jsp, struts2

Below is my sign in form created using bootstrap version 3 in a home.jsp file, I want to use struts2 tags along with these bootstrap theme. I am using struts2 version 2.0.11. Please suggest which plugins do I need to import and how to add that in my jsp to get the functionality working.

```html
<div class="modal-body">
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="why">
<p>We need this information so that you can receive access to the site and its content. Rest assured your information will not be sold, traded, or given to anyone.</p>
<p></p><br> Please contact <a mailto:href="JoeSixPack@Sixpacksrus.com"></a>JoeSixPack@Sixpacksrus.com</a> for any other inquiries.</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="signin">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
    <!-- Sign In Form -->
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="userid">Username:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input required="" id="userid" name="userid" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" class="input-medium" required="true">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Password input-->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="passwordinput">Password:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input required="true" id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-medium">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="rememberme"></label>
      <div class="controls">
        <label class="" for="rememberme-0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme-0" value="Remember me">&nbsp;&nbsp;Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="signin"></label>
      <div class="controls middleAlign">
        <button id="signin" name="signin" class="btn btn-success middleAlign">Sign In</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Struts 2.0.11 is outdated, you should upgrade to the latest version to be able to use bootstrap plugin.

Comment: This is a broad question which shows you lack programming basics and have not performed any research. Please change that before you post questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Struts 2.0.11 is outdated, you should upgrade to the latest version to be able to use bootstrap plugin.

The Struts2 bootstrap plugin is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-bootstrap/).